# ConstraintLayout as RecyclerView Items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use `ConstraintLayout` as `RecyclerView` item. But now there are some problems that are displayed on the real machine and in the preview is not the same

The recyclerView item layout as follow:

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/foreground_item_undo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread">

    <com.lsl.wordhelper.view.RoundBgTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="G"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_explain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="释义："
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tv_item_original"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_original"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Good"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_item_explain"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_item_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_translate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="很好"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tv_item_original"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_item_explain" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="2018/01/19"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_date"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_item_original"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In Android Studio preview .
[image]

But on the phone
[image]

What's the problem?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

in you code:
`layout_marginStart`and`layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf` didn't same ,you should use 
`layout_marginStart`and`layout_constraintStart_toStartOf` or `layout_margintLeft`and`layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf`,keep same. left and start is diffent in some time.
see that get more if you want to make constraintlayout as recyclerview.
https://developer.android.google.cn/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html.

Answer (score 5):

Update oncreateView of the adapter with this :

```kotlin
//view is what we return from onCreateViewHolder
view.apply {
    this.layoutParams = RecyclerView.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
}
```

This always works.

Comment: At last a solution that works! Thanks for sharing. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what the accepted answer suggests, this has nothing to do with Chains.

This behavior is a bug in the constraint layout and was fixed in beta5, so upgrade your dependency to `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta5` or newer. It's out of beta now, so you should use `1.1.0`.

Comment: I am using 1.1.3 and facing the exact same issues when using it as a Recycler view item. Would you be able to suggest anything further?

Comment: Using 2.0.4 the issue is still present.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tv_item_explain"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tv_item_icon"
```

If `@id/tv_item_explain` was created below the current View, it will cause error .

You can add `@id/tv_item_explain`

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_item_explain"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_item_icon"
```

You can try like this .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/foreground_item_undo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="spread">

<com.lsl.wordhelper.view.RoundBgTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:text="G"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_explain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="释义："
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/tv_item_original"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_original"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="Good"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_item_explain"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tv_item_icon"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_translate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="很好"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/tv_item_original"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_item_explain"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_item_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="2018/01/19"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tv_item_original"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this problem and it was down to the inflation of the list view items. In my `onCreateViewHolder` I inflate a layout using databinding and needed to call the inflation method which takes the parent root, so instead of this:

`ItemLineItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))`

I needed this:

`ItemLineItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)`

Which ensures the constraints of the parent are used I guess.